# PostgreSQL group by 24 hour period noon to noon

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, aggregation

Using PostgreSQL I need to be able to aggregate data, as the title suggests, in 24 hour periods but from noon to noon. The data is collected every 5 minutes over a period of several weeks and I want to average the readings over 24 hour periods from 12:00 noon of first day to 12:00 noon of the next day until the end of the data.

For a more standard midnight to midnight grouping I can use the example below, which works just fine, but I can't see work out how to adapt this to the noon-noon time-span I need.

```
group by date_trunc('day', <DateCol>)
```

PostgreSQL is relatively new to me, and if I was going to do this in SQL Server I'd use:

```
dateadd(hour, (datepart(hour, <DateCol>)/12)*12, dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, <DateCol>)))
```

As far as I can tell from reading the documentation at [http://www.postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html) there is no equivalent to `date add`. Is there a way to do what is required within PostgreSQL?

Comment: In standard SQL, you add to a date by adding a value of type "interval", as `select current_date + interval '12' hour;`. PostgreSQL more or less follows standard SQL for date arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, this is what pretty much got me there, although it's a step further to get the final grouping, which is obtained using: `GROUP BY date_trunc('day', <DateCol> + interval '12h') + interval '12h'`. Oddly easier than I expected.

Answer (score 3):

Try grouping by day on date - 12hours:

```
group by date_trunc('day', <DateCol> - INTERVAL '12 hours')
```